# Is this regex pattern wrong?

Tags: java, regex

Getting weird output from this code.

- Number of capturing groups: 3
- Found value(capturint group(1)): This order was placed for QT300
- Found value(capturint group(2)): 0
- Found value(capturint group(3)): ! OK?

Shouldn't the regex break on the first '3' since it's first digit after all the char's?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CaptureGroups1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";

        String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        int count = m.groupCount();

        System.out.println("Number of capturing groups: " + count + '\n');

        if (m.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                System.out.println("Found value(capturint group(" + i + ")): " + m.group(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's correct depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis As he wants to capture more than one group, I don't think it can be considered correct.

Comment: Posting a block of code and just saying, "*is this wrong?*" isn't going to get you anywhere. Describe what you want to happen and tell us if there are any errors / unexpected results.

Comment: What is the expected result for `I have 3 pigs. I had 5, but 2 of them died` ?

Comment: @dystroy You're inferring what he wants based on the code :). He may just want the first group to be the entire string, and the others to be empty. It would be a dumb requirement is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is wrong in your sense.
I suspect you're looking for this.

```
String pattern = "(\\D*)(\\d+)(.*)";
```

Maybe you want to check reluctant quantifiers too.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: I base my answer on the assumption that OP wants to get the number.

Comment: Can someone elaborate as to how the pattern actually matches against the string from the given regex. Maybe i'm missing something. Doesn't my regex translate to match any amount of char's followed by 1 or more digits followed by any amount of char's again?

Comment: I don't actually think you need the reluctant qualifier at all here

Comment: @user2130360 The problem is the "any amount of characters" will consume all of those digits

Comment: @user2130360 Correct. So my assumption is correct. But you're missing the reluctant quantifier.

Comment: @Cruncher OK, good point. Corrected.

Comment: @Cruncher are you saying that the first (.*) consumes the entire string? I thought that a digit was a digit specifically so it can't be counted as a char?

Comment: @user2130360 `.` matches ANY character. `1` is a character. The character class that peter uses in his answer, matches any non-digit character. Alternative to `\\D*` you could use `.*?` which matches all characters until it matches the next thing in the regex

Comment: @Cruncher "(.*)?(\\d+)(.*)" doesn't work for some reason. Doesn't do what my regexp does. Right now I am not sure why btw :)

Comment: @peter.petrov Hmm, where are you testing this? Can you give me a sample?

Comment: @Cruncher I am testing it on my computer :) Take OP's code and try what we're discussing.

Comment: @peter.petrov needs to be `(.*?)` not `(.*)?`. My using (.*)? you're not actually even using a reluctant quantifier, you're using a greedy one, but just saying that "it's okay if it didn't match anything". It matches the last 0 under `\\d+` because after it hits the end it backtracks to try to satisfy the other groups.

Comment: @Cruncher Right, I see now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the Numeric groups, probably removing the parenthesis from `(.*)` would help you out. Actually, you don't even need them:

```
String pattern = "(\\d+)";
```

Comment: Sorry guys I struggled with putting the ouput it kept complaining about it not being formatted.... I wanted to know why this pattern is not breaking the string up into what i expected. How do you even add a newline in this place?? it outputs :                                             
    Number of capturing groups: 3 \n
    
    Found value(capturint group(1)): This order was placed for QT300
    Found value(capturint group(2)): 0
    Found value(capturint group(3)): ! OK?

Comment: <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html>